# In LWC how to make the required mandatory field check on child component value

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template> <!--Parent component-->

 <c-child-component></c-child-component> -> this child component has multiple checkbox's how to make required to check one checkbox value 

</template>

child component code

 <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" >
            <template for:each={fieldValues} for:item="item">
                <lightning-layout-item size="4" class="cn-checkbox mb-2 canon-checkbox" key={item.value}>
                    <input type="checkbox" id={item.value} value={item.value} name={item.value} onchange={handleSelect} checked={item.isChecked} />
                    &nbsp;<label class="cn-checkbox__label" for={item.value}>{item.value}</label>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the list **fieldValues** and there is attribute **isChecked** in it. So if anyone is clicking on submit or continue you throw a error if no item in list is checked.

Or you can make continue or submit button disable till the time any of the check box is checked using getter.